# Side table forest plot made with ggplot

Tags: r

I making forest plot by using ggplot.
Here is my sample data

```
D<–data.frame(metabolite,expb,lower95,upper95)

 $ metabolite: Factor w/ 70 levels "IDL.C_proc","IDL.CE_proc",..: 69 66 67 68 70 59 56 57 58 60 ...
 $ expbeta   : num  -1.355 0.545 0.3 1.224 -0.861 ...
 $ lower95   : num  -2.589 1.034 0.809 -0.346 -0.666 ...
 $ upper95   : num  -0.2617 0.0916 -0.0561 1.3656 -0.5855 ...
```

Here `metabolite` is column with variable names, `expb` is expcoef and `lower95`, `upper95` are conf.ivals.

I use ggplot to make forest plot

```
forestplot <- function(d, xlab="HR", ylab=""){
  require(ggplot2)
  p <- ggplot(d, aes(x=d$metabolite, y=d$expb, ymin=d$lower95, ymax=d$upper95)) + 
    geom_pointrange() + 
    coord_flip() +
    geom_hline(aes(x=0,yintercept=1), lty=2) +
    ylab(xlab) +
    xlab(ylab) #switch because of the coord_flip() above
  return(p)}
forestplot(d)
```

How can I modify forest plot to have side table of con.ivals and pvalues?

Thank you for any tips.

Comment: while there are packages and other related questions on SO, I think you can grab the code you need from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30464484/custom-forest-plot-with-with-ggplot2-cant-have-multiple-groups-cis-cross-the